# html date input -> php -> sql not working

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hey i have some Problemes with my Registration Form

```
if(isset($_GET['register'])) {
    $error = false;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $nachname = $_POST['nachname'];
    $vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
    $geburtsdatum =new DateTime( $_POST['geburtsdatum']);
    $strasse = $_POST['strasse'];
    $hausnummer = $_POST['hausnummer'];
    $plz = $_POST['plz'];
    $ort = $_POST['ort'];
    $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
    $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
    $passwort2 = $_POST['passwort2'];
```

Warning: Undefined array key "geburtsdatum" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\register.php on line 17

After that i do some Error Questions...

and than i want to insert this in my Database

```
if(!$error) {    
        $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO kunde (KEMAIL,NACHNAME,VORNAME,GEBURTSDATUM,STRASSE,HAUSNR,PLZ,ORT,TELEFON,PASSWORT) 
                                    VALUES (:kemail,:nachname,:vorname,:geburtsdatum,:strasse,:hausnummer,:plz,:ort,telefon,:passwort)");
        $result = $statement->execute(array('KEMAIL' => $email,'NACHNAME' => $nachname,'VORNAME' => $vorname, 'GEBURTSDATUM' => $geburtsdatum,'STRASSE' => $strasse,'HAUSNR' => $hausnummer,'PLZ' => $plz,'ORT' => $ort,'TELEFON' => $telefon,   'passwort' => $passwort_hash));
        
        if($result) {        
            echo 'Du wurdest erfolgreich registriert. <a href="login.php">Zum Login</a>';
            $showFormular = false;
        } else {
            echo 'Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten<br>';
        }
    } 
}
```

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\register.php:60 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\register.php(60): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\register.php on line 60

the problem is in this line

```
$result = $statement->execute(array('KEMAIL' => $email,'NACHNAME' => $nachname,'VORNAME' => $vorname, 'GEBURTSDATUM' => $geburtsdatum,'STRASSE' => $strasse,'HAUSNR' => $hausnummer,'PLZ' => $plz,'ORT' => $ort,'TELEFON' => $telefon,   'passwort' => $passwort_hash));
```

This is my Database [image: My Data Base]

Pls Help Maybe something with time to string is broken but i already have time as a Date Type in my Data base

Comment: What is the form input for `geburtsdatum`? Or the whole form.

Comment: 1. You've misnamed the field `geburtsdatum` somewhere, probably in the form source. 2. Format the date. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php 3. If you don't fix #1 before #2 the date will be "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the DateTime object as it is, but MySQL cannot accept an object as input. So you may have to convert your DateTime object ($geburtsdatum) to the format that MySQL date type which is YYY-MM-DD format.

```
$date = new DateTime( $_POST['geburtsdatum']);
$geburtsdatum = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

I hope this will solve your problem. For more information checkout [php datetime formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), [php datetime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), and [MySQL Date type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)